# How to get ListView item content on RightTapped event of an Universal Windows app?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

I've got a ListView with an MenuFlyout as it follows:

```
<Page
x:Class="BibleApp.View.BiblePage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:BibleApp.View"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
xmlns:data="using:BibleApp.Domain" Loaded="Page_Loaded">

<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="VerseListDataTemplate" x:DataType="data:Verse">
        <Grid x:Name="gridVerses" Padding="0,20,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Number}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Text}"  Margin="30,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="auto" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">        

    <ListView x:Name="lvVerses" 
              Margin="10,100,10,10" 
              Height="auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource VerseListDataTemplate}"
              SelectionMode="Multiple"                  
              SelectionChanged="lvVerses_SelectionChanged"
              RightTapped="lvVerses_RightTapped"
              IsRightTapEnabled="True">

        <ListView.Resources>
            <MenuFlyout x:Name="menuFlyout">
                <MenuFlyout.Items>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Name="Copy" Text="Copy" Click="Copy_Click"/>
                </MenuFlyout.Items>
            </MenuFlyout>
        </ListView.Resources>

    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

In the code behind I got these:

```
private void Copy_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{                        
    DataPackage dataPackage = new DataPackage();
    dataPackage.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;
    dataPackage.SetText("Hello World!");
    Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
}

private void lvVerses_RightTapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    menuFlyout.ShowAt(lvVerses, e.GetPosition(this.lvVerses));
}
```

When the user makes a right click or right tap on one of the listview items the MenuFlyout is raised with the "Copy" MenuFlyoutItem. When the user clicks in the "Copy" MenuFlyoutItem I want to send the listview item content to the clipboard as a string.

What I need is to get the "right_tapped" listview item content in one of these two events.

Comment: ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext should contain the item content in the right tapped event.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I appreciate it.